# First Capturing thumbnail from a Video using php?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have an upload functionality on my site. And i want the php script to take out a random frame from the uploaded video, and save it as an image. Is that possible?please guide me how can i get first capture image in video upload in php

Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need `ffmpeg` installed on your server.

With that, use the `exec()` function:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i /path/to/your/video.avi -f image2 -vframes 1 /path/to/thumbnail.jpg');
```

Take a look at the [Flowplayer Tutorial](http://flowplayer.org/tutorials/generating-thumbs.html) or the [ffmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) for more options

Comment: how can i search my server support ffmpeg or not?just i check php info but i don't know exactly please guide me

Comment: hi.i am using like this $cardvideo=$date."card.mp4";
$tmppath3="services/video/".$cardvideo;$thumb=$date.".jpg";$thumbDirectory="services/VideoCapturePic/";exec('ffmpeg -i $tmppath3 -f image2 -vframes 1 $thumbDirectory$thumb'); this not working for me

Comment: @user816891 you can use phpinfo(); to tell you if ffmpeg is supported. once on the phpinfo() debug script search for 'ffmpeg'... if it is installed you will see it ... otherwise you will have to compile it if it is a linux server ... or you can use a pre-compiled DLL if it is a windows os ... for ffmpeg for windows os you can have a look at http://whatsthisbuzz.pcriot.com/portfolio/blog/2011/11/ffmpeg_php-for-windows/

Comment: @user816891 In your comment above you are using the variables within a single quoted string `'`, that doesn't work. Use double quotes `"` or concatenate the strings

Comment: hi do u have any idea about how to install ffmeg into server i see many fourms but i'm getting clear idea

Comment: The option to skip to a frame in the video instead of the capturing the first frame which is usually not preferred because in most video files the first frame is blank. use "-ss 5" option before the -i where 5 is 5 seconds from the start of the file.